# CSV imported into SAS via EG not showing column names when opened in base SAS

Tags: sas

I am using sas 9.4 and used the enterprise guide's Import data feature to import a csv file. The csv had no field names, so I supplied them using the wizard.

I saved the  file in a library. When I open bases SAS and go to the library, the field names i provided are all gone.

Comment: What names are there instead? Is your IMPORT DATA process step the only one that is writing to that dataset?  Perhaps something else replaced the file you created.

Comment: Run a PROC CONTENTS on the data set in EG and then in Base after you exist. Show the output please.